# Angular sort items in object

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, pipe, ngfor

MARKUP

```
 <ion-content>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let todosPaises of crossCountriesData">
        <ion-item lines="inset" *ngFor="let dados of todosPaises.response | orderBy">
            {{ dados.cases.active }}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
this.crossCountries = this.api.getCrossCountries();
        this.crossCountries.forEach(item => {
            this.crossCountriesData.push(item);
            console.log('my data: ', this.crossCountriesData);
        });
```

PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "orderBy"
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: object[], sortFunction?: any): any[] {
    return value.sort(sortFunction);
  }
}
```

OBJECT

[image]

QUESTION

In a IONIC app i'm trying to sort from greater to smallest by number of active cases, but the pipe i made is not solving the issue.

Can anyone show me the proper way?

Comment: response.sort((a, b) => a.cases.active > b.cases.active ? 1 : -1);                                                              you can checkout this article https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-by-property-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OrderByPipe` function takes an additional argument which is the function passed to `sort`, looking at your code, that function is never passed, you should define such a function in your component next pass it to the pipe as an argument, as demonstrated below:

**Component:**

```js
public orderByMethod = (x, y) => y.cases.active - x.cases.active;
```

**Template:**

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let todosPaises of crossCountriesData">
    <ion-item lines="inset"
      *ngFor="let dados of todosPaises.response | orderBy : orderByMethod">
      {{ dados.cases.active }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I was missing the function to sort in my controller.
It is working now.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to sort in multiple places in your App then **Pipe** is recommended but here you can do it with by adding a new method.

Try to change your code like below,

```
 ...

   this.crossCountries = this.api.getCrossCountries();
    sortData('activeCases');
}    

sortData(value: string) {
  this.crossCountries.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a[value] < b[value]) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a[value] > b[value]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
  this.crossCountriesData = this.countriesData;
}
```

Happy Coding..  :)

Comment: Thank you for the good answer, Indeed i need to sort in multiple places, thats why i implemented a pipe.

Comment: NP, it can be useful for someone who came here with this scenario..